# What is the iOS autolayout constraint (greaterThanOrEquall) equivalent thing on Android?

Tags: android, ios, autolayout, android-relativelayout, android-constraintlayout

I am trying to do some constraints on Android XML, which looks very difficult and unspecific.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ViewswithIntrinsicContentSize.html

For example:

[image]

I know how to express the equal relation on android XML using ConstraintLayout. Even though, I still need padding or margin for the offset of 30, that's not a big problem.

But how to do the "greater" relation? 
I saw there are something called "maxWidth", "maxHeight", "miniWidth", "miniHeight". But they are not the relation between view. Although it's possible to use them on some fake views between real views, then it might be possible to do the "greater".

Are there any other methods could solve it?

Comment: Layout mechanisms for Android and iOS are quite different. There is no greaterThanOrEqual equivalent. As-is your question is unanswerable because it is not clear what are you trying to achieve. Please include your layout and code (minimal one that shows your issue) and explain what you have tried and what you actually need.

Comment: If you have a basic description or picture of the layout you are trying to achieve. I could give you the constraint you would need. ConstraintLayout is not AutoLayout. In some ways all Constraints are greater than equal. More correctly  something like  Right(w1)  = Right(w2) - margin + error. Where errors are minimized and balanced.

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to translate autolayout to android, so there should not be specific example. I think there will be many methods to solve it when it is specific. But I need to find a generic solution. @DalijaPrasnikar

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no generic solution. You will have to find specific solutions for specific problems as you go.

Comment: Hi @hoford that is not a specific problem, you can reference to that short introduction from Apple. https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/nslayoutconstraint 
Then, here are some examples with pictures https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ViewswithIntrinsicContentSize.html

Answer (score 1):

Here is a perfect solution from "Cassowary", although there are not too many stars, I am not sure about the performance. It's based on the same algorithm with autolayout on iOS.

https://github.com/alexbirkett/android-cassowary-layout
http://constraints.cs.washington.edu/cassowary

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_FYroNxqFqo

So, I can use Greater or Less in the natural way. And it also has priorities for constraints. But, it looks like there is no content hugging and compression priorities.

```
<string-array name="stairs">

    <item>blue.x == 0</item>
    <item>blue.y == 0</item>**strong text**
    <item>blue.width == 100dp</item>
    <item>blue.height == blue.width</item>

    <item>green.width == blue.width</item>
    <item>green.height == blue.height</item>
    <item>green.x == blue.y2</item>
    <item>green.y == blue.y2</item>

    <item>red.width == green.width</item>
    <item>red.height == green.height</item>
    <item>red.x == green.x2</item>
    <item>red.y == green.y2</item>

    <item>container.width GEQ red.right</item>
    <item>container.height GEQ red.bottom</item>

</string-array>
```